# calling numbered function name in loop using java reflection

Tags: java, function, reflection

i have a problem as :
MyFirstClass.java

```
public class MyFirstClass{
  String strParam;
  MySecondClass secClass;
  //getters and setters
}
```

MySecondClass.java

```
public class MySecondClass{
  String p1Param;
  String p2Param;
  String p3Param;
  String p4Param;
//setters and getters
}
```

TestClass.java

```
public void doProcessing(MyFirstClass pObj){
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
  System.out.println() ;
  //###question is here
}
```

I want to use java reflection and call the pObj.getP**Param() methods in for loop by providing the parameters to g

```
Method m= cls.getMethod("getP"+(i+1)+"Param");
pObj.getSecClass.[ invokeMethod m ]
```

How it can be made possible. 
I don't want to use array of p*Params.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure this is what you need? For me, your code seems to be a typical example of the current trend of abusing reflection for every task. Why don't you use arrays or maps to store the properties `p[0-9]+Param`.

Arrays were invented to do exactly that. They provide a range of variables, indexed by numbers.

Comment: @gt_ebuddy: Then get rid of the reflection code simulate arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Once you have the `Method` object, just call it like this:

```
String param = (String) m.invoke(pObj.getSecClass());
```

Note that such reflection games can lead to hard-to-grasp and complicated code that can be hard to maintain. If you told us what the numbered parameters represent, then we could provide a better solution (possibly a single parameter that is a `List<String>`?).

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes obviously the List<String> is good option. The above question

Comment: Yes obviously the List<String> is good option. I just think of doing the same by using reflection and got consfused and asked the question. thanks for the reply...

Comment: <<i pressed ENTER key to create new line, but Add Comment Button was pressed.>>

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
Object result = m.invoke(pObj.getSecClass)
```